# Where should I position a recessed contact sensor in a door?

Tags: security

Is there a recommended location on a door to install a recessed contact sensor?  I see many installing on the top of the door.  Any reason it can't be installed in the bottom corner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, there is no right or wrong here. The preferred location is either the top of the door or on the side (either hinges-side or the opposite of). You will want to place the sensor so it is easier for you to wire it to the control panel. For example, if this is the basement door and the control panel is on the top floor; you may want to install the sensor on top of the door so you can directly wire it up.

Answer (score 2):

Foot traffic.  Things on the bottom of the door get kicked, and thus are more prone to break.

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased the question differently.  I meant on the side opposite the hinges, but either on the top or bottom on that side.

Comment: The side opposite the hinges meaning the latch side - the side that swings open and closed?  In which case my answer still stands - stuff near the floor gets kicked.  Stuff near the ceiling doesn't

Comment: The side that swings open.  They are recessed though, so I guess I don't see why there would be any issue, unless I have a pile of poo or something on my shoe, and somehow find a way to magically kick it in the air, which in that case it may just as easily land on the top of the door (if I'm good enough).